# PHP, ping a list of IPs?

Tags: php

I have a list of IPs which I want to ping via PHP (to save me the trouble of manually doing it via SSH).

I can run exec, escapeshellarg, system etc on my server - how would I create a script to ping an IP once and return the response time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why? I suspect you should look at a more apposite tool for the job, e.g. nagios.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1');
print $output;
```

Comment: When running this script nothing happens, although other things such as "shell_exec('ls -lart')" do work.

Comment: When I run it via SSH, it responds: "connect: Invalid Argument" but if I just use "ping google.com" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the shell ping, use `shell_exec` for this.

However...here you can find an excellent example on how to ping via PHP:

http://birk-jensen.dk/2010/09/php-ping/

This script can be easily adapted with php timers to return response times.

Comment: I've tried this already but it gave me an error: "Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted"

Comment: The class is using `SOCK_RAW` to create the socket. It might be you need root privilegues on your machine to execute this code. If this any issue with your enviroment, then fall back to `shell_exec`.